# Python telnetlib determining different login prompts

Tags: python, telnetlib

I've written a python script that can log into multiple devices sequentially by reading a csv file listing the different IP addresses. From there it outputs a file for each device with the content from a few commands that are passed to the devices via the script. So I've come pretty far. A problem I'm running into is that sometimes the script hangs. And that is because some devices have different software revisions and do not support certain commands that are being passed to them. The difference I'm focusing on is the prompt after log in. For example, logging into device type A has a command prompt of xyz#. Device type B has a command type abc:. It's the same manufacturer, just a different model and/or software rev. Depending on the command prompt I know the commands I can run on that device without the script hanging up. So what I need to be able to do is after a successful login, depending on the command prompt I get run a set of specific commands.

I can post some of my code if that would help but what I'm really looking to find out is if this is even possible. And if so, so pointers. A few suggestions on what I might try. After working with Python for a few months I know there has to be a way to do this. I usually don't post because I can work through others' posts and develop a working solution. But I've been working on this a bit and haven't been able to piece it together so looking I'm for an assist.

-Shane

EDIT

At this point I'm still unable to write code the would determine the command prompt. Well at least while the telnet session is up. I can telnet in, run some commands and close the session. I can then write the results to a file. And from there read the file to determine the prompt. But ideally I'd like to be able to open a telnet session, run a command to determine the prompt while the session is still open, read it while the session is up and then based on the prompt run specific commands.

The issue seems to be with not being able to read any command output while the telnet session is still up. The session has to close and then write all output to a file. Then read the file to determine the command prompt, determine which commands to run based on the prompt, then open a new telnet session and run those commands.

Should I accept the fact that I have to close the telnet session, write the data to a file, read it to determine prompt and then loop back through the login part of the script again? Or am I missing something? Not sure if I'm bring clear in my description.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the commands using a common interface and then use a dictionary to retrieve them when I know what system I am connected to:

```
# command set for system xyz#
def copy1(src, dest):
  pass

def list1():
  pass

# command set for system abc:
def copy2(src, dest):
  pass

def list2():
  pass


cmdDict = {
   # prompt  command set
   'xyz#':   [copy1, list1],
   'abc:'    [copy2, list2],
}

...

# guess the right commands from the prompt we have read
copyCommand = cmdDict[detected_prompt][0]
listCommand = cmdDict[detected_prompt][1]

...

# proceed normally

listCommand()
copyCommand(f1, g1)
copyCommand(f2, g2)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'll try to work this into my script and come back with my results.